# How to center text and a rule in a heading

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment

I'm working on my resume, found a nice [template](http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_resume_cv_latex_example.php) as a starting place, but I want my name to be centered on the top above a horizontal rule. Also, rather than two arguments, I just want one,  my name.  I would have like to have simplified that part away already, but when I remove the second argument, I start getting the below error, which I don't understand:

> LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

```
\newcommand{\makeheading}[2][]
{
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
{\Large \scshape{ #2 \hfill #1}}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]
\rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}
\end{minipage}
}
```

How can I modify this new command to take just the name argument, and produce a centered heading above the same horizontal rule?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `center` environment instead of `minipage`.

```
\newcommand{\makeheading}[1]%
{%
\begin{center}%
{\Large \scshape{#1}}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]%
\rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}%
\end{center}
}
```

Building on egreg's comment to remove the extra padding before and after the heading, you can use the following,

```
\newcommand{\makeheading}[1]%
{%
\centerline{\Large \textsc{#1}}\vspace{-0.15\baselineskip}%
\noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}%
}
```

This gives the following difference in padding:
[image: Difference in padding between two cases]

Comment: This will add some padding space above and below; possibly better: `\newcommand{\makeheading{{\centering{\Large\scshape #1}\\[-.15\baselineskip]\rule{\columnwidth}{.4pt}\par}}` (so with an additional pair of braces).

Comment: ok, I tried the `center` environment inside `minipage`.  I see now why that was a mistake.   With the code you provide, I'm getting the error again: `There's no line here to end.`

Comment: never mind, verbatim copy and paste, and it works.  Thanks.  Something about innocuous looking white space seems to screw things up.

Comment: @egreg thank you, I have updated the answer to show the difference.